# WAMP server fails to stars if I load mod_wsgi.so

Tags: apache, wamp, mod-wsgi

I've read many other answers about the subject but couldn't find a solution to mine. Even uninstalled everything and re-installed...

OS    Win8-64bit

Wamp  64-bit, Apache : 2.4.4 MySQL : 5.6.12 PHP : 5.4.12 PHPMyAdmin : 4.0.4 SqlBuddy : 1.3.3
              XDebug : 2.2.3

I downloaded 64-bit wsgi from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi).
Everything I installed is 64 bit.

When I add `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so` to httpd.conf WAMP failed to start, removing it solves the problem...

Apache log:

```
[Thu Aug 29 13:50:38.914739 2013]
[mpm_winnt:notice]
[pid 6124:tid 380]
AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) configured -- resuming normal operations [Thu Aug 29 13:50:38.914739 2013]

[mpm_winnt:notice]
[pid 6124:tid 380]
AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37 [Thu Aug 29 13:50:38.914739 2013]

[core:notice]
[pid 6124:tid 380]
AH00094: Command line: 'c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.4\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4' [Thu Aug 29 13:50:38.914739 2013]

[mpm_winnt:notice]
[pid 6124:tid 380]
AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3624 [Thu Aug 29 13:50:39.308626 2013]

[mpm_winnt:notice]
[pid 3624:tid 260]
AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads. [Thu Aug 29 13:52:03.007076 2013]

[mpm_winnt:notice]
[pid 6124:tid 380]
AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server. [Thu Aug 29 13:52:05.009448 2013]

[mpm_winnt:notice]
[pid 3624:tid 260]
AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited. [Thu Aug 29 13:52:05.023457 2013]

[mpm_winnt:notice]
[pid 6124:tid 380]
AH00430: Parent: Child process 3624 exited successfully. [Thu Aug 29 13:59:22.716409 2013]

[mpm_winnt:notice]
[pid 5948:tid 376]
AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) configured -- resuming normal operations [Thu Aug 29 13:59:22.717411 2013]

[mpm_winnt:notice]
[pid 5948:tid 376]
AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37 [Thu Aug 29 13:59:22.717411 2013]

[core:notice]
[pid 5948:tid 376]
AH00094: Command line: 'c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.4\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4' [Thu Aug 29 13:59:22.717411 2013]

[mpm_winnt:notice]
[pid 5948:tid 376]
AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5956 [Thu Aug 29 13:59:22.963535 2013]

[mpm_winnt:notice]
[pid 5956:tid 252]
AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: I can't paste the log in a readable way... the critical line when it fails is : Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.

Comment: Was the correct Python version for the mod_wsgi.so used installed? Was is also 64 bit and was the Python installation installed for all users on the system? It cannot be installed for just the user that installed Python as Apache will not run as that user and so will not find it properly.

Comment: I have 64bit python, for all users.

Is there anyway to debug this thing?

Comment: Did you use the Apache binary that the page you got mod_wsgi from says it was built against?